# how to store edited data in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

This is my function which binds data in *textbox* and i want to update data using this in local storage, i want to store new data.
Please guide me how to publish new data in local storage at given point

```js
function view(email) {
    $("#one").remove();
    var e = email;
    var $header = $("<h2 align='center' id='tab'>Edit User Details</h2><br>");
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person'));
    var $foot = $("<div class='modal-footer'>&copy; akhil trivedi</div>");
    myObject = data.filter(function(person) {
        return person.email == email;
    });

    var $div1 = $("<div class='col-md-7 col-md-offset-3'></div><br>");
    for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
        var $line2 = $("<form class='form-group'></form>");
        if (myObject[i].member == "yes") {
            $line2.append($("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-inline' id='test' name='test' checked='checked' disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Already Member</label><br><br>").val(myObject[i].member));
        } else {
            $line2.append($("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-inline' id='test' name='test'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Want to become Member ?</label><br><br>").val(myObject[i].member));
        }
        //$line2.append( $("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='test' name='test' checked='checked'><label>Member ?</label><br><br>").val(emp.member));
        $line2.append($("<input  type='text' class='form-control' value='' required><br><br>").val(myObject[i].name));
        $line2.append($("<input  type='email' class='form-control' value='' required><br><br>").val(myObject[i].email));
        $line2.append($("<input  type='tel' id='phone' class='form-control' value='9' name='phone' required><br><br>").val(myObject[i].mobile).mask("(999) 999-9999"));
        $line2.append($("<input type='submit' onclick='updatedata(\"" + myObject[i].email + "\")'>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<select class='form-control'><option>select</option><option>zen</option><option>alto</option><option>wagonr</option></select>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<select class='form-control'><option>select</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option><option>2015</option></select>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<br>"));
        $line2.append($("<h2 align='center' id='tab'>Car Owned</h2>"));
        $line2.append($("<table class='table table-responsive'><thead><th>Car</th><th>year</th><th>delete</th></thead><tr><td>" + myObject[i].car + "</td><td>" + myObject[i].year + "</td><td><a href='' onclick='deletecar(\"" + myObject[i].email + "\")'><img src='images/delete.png'></a></td></tr></table>"));
        $div1.append($header);
        $div1.append($line2);
        $div1.append($foot);
        $div1.appendTo(document.body);
    }
}
```

This is my update function

```
function updatedata(email) {
    debugger
    var newd = [{
        "name": myObject[0].name,
        "email": myObject[0].email,
        "phone": myObject[0].mobile,
        "car": myObject[0].car,
        "year": myObject[0].year,
        "member": myObject[0].member
    }];
    localStorage.setItem("person", JSON.stringify(newd));
}
```

this is my local storage array

```
[{
    "email": "akhiltrivedi@outlook.com",
    "pass": "akhil@1",
    "name": "akhil",
    "car": "zen",
    "year": "2014",
    "member": "no",
    "mobile": "9033098795"
}, {
    "email": "anandpatel@gmail.com",
    "pass": "Smith@1",
    "name": "suresh",
    "car": "alto",
    "year": "2015",
    "member": "yes",
    "mobile": "9998789333"
}, {
    "email": "contact@akhiltrivedi.com",
    "pass@1": "akhil@1",
    "name": "rakesh",
    "car": "wagonr",
    "year": "2016",
    "member": "no",
    "mobile": "9033098794"
}]
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? which part is not working?

Comment: Data are binding ini textbox but if i edit binded data then new data are not  updated in local storage

Comment: @AkhilTrivedi have you tried setting a `change` eventListener on the input?

Comment: where to use change ?

Comment: what to pass on onchange event ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AkhilTrivedi like this `$("#email").change(function () { // TODO your updating code here... } );`

And why is your `updatedata` function getting values from `myObject` object ? you should get them from the form you have created, that is why it's not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see you facing any problems here as you have got the 'how to save' part figured.

If you are wondering on when to save to the localstorage I would say it is always depends on what you are trying to do.

In most cases you can use the `onblur` or `onchange` DOM event to save the value of the input to the localstorage. This can be particularly useful when you want to save an un submitted form so that user can resume when he visits the page again.

```
$line2.append($("<input  type='text' class='form-control' value='' onchange='updateData(\"name\",this.value)' required><br><br>").val(myObject[i].name));
```

And update your `updateData` function to use a switch case to update appropriate value in your localstorage.

But in cases where say you donot have any server storage mechanism or not planning for any you can always save the form data to the local storage on submission of the form.

Just like I said before 'when to save' is really upto your requirement.

You could also use a library [autoStorage](https://github.com/phunkei/autoStorage) which can help you store entire form data on form submission and retrieve them when user visits the page again.